# Which is a better way to extract grayscale pixel values in Android in terms of battery drain and processing time?

Tags: android, performance

hope you are all well.

I am at a somewhat of a crossroads in my current project, I am needing to extract grayscale pixel values that will be sorted as per the discussion in my previous post (and very kindly and thoroughly answered).

The two main methods that I am aware of are:

1. Extract the grayscale from the Yuv preview.
2. Take the photo, and convert the RGB values to grayscale.

One of my main aims is simplicity, the project as a whole needs it, so thus my question - whaich of these two (or another method I am not aware of) would be the most reliable/stable, but would be less taxing on the battery and processing time?

Please note, I am not after any code samples, but are looking for what people may have experienced, may hve read (in articles etc) or have a intuitive hunch about.

Thank you for taking the time to read this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm currently working on a project which also uses pixel values to do some calculations, and I noticed that it's better to use the values directly from the YUV preview if you only need the grayscale, or need to use the entire preview for your calculation.

If you want to use the RGB values, or only calculate something based on a certain part of the preview it's better to convert the area you need by converting to a Bitmap and using that for instance.

However, it all depends on what you're trying to achieve since no two projects are alike. If you have the time, why not (rougly) implement both methods and do a quick test to see what works better in terms of cpu usage and total processing time? That's how I found the best method for my particular problem.

Comment: Thank you for this, Sander.  It is good advice - time is indeed against me somewhat (full time study as well as full time work), I think it'd be prudent to test both methods - but starting with the YUV preview.